# Using RewriteRule causes index file to be unreadable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Here is my setup:
http://example.com/directory/

I am trying to hide "directory" when loading pages within that folder. I update my .htaccess file in the html root to this:

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>   RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)directory 
>
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ directory/$1

This works great when loading a file in the directory folder, but index.html in the html root folder is not found unless I put it within the directory folder. Thanks in advance for any help. I've gone over every bit of rewrite Q&A on this site!

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule to me looks like your taking requests from the root directory and appending the filename onto /directory/. That would explain why files in the root directly aren't working unless also present in the /directory/ folder.

Comment: but "directory" is successfully hidden in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

dougajmcdonald explained enough but I explain in another way, so the bounty is his:-)

when you request `index.html` file, mod-rewrite checks your rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.)directory
```

because  its request URI is something like `/index.html` and it  matches the condition ( your condition: request URI should NOT be starting with `/directory` )
So, mod_rewrite rewrites your URL to new one: `directory/index.html`
that's equal to requesting `directory/index.html` by yourself. that's the reason you should put that file in **"directory"** directory.

Comment: Thanks! uh... Death :)
You mean the htaccess file should go in directory, right?

Comment: @dwarbi no, if you put that **.htaccess** in **directory**, you just added another **directory**, if you want to use some files in root folder, you should add another condition for that!